'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 14: invalid start byte' how to solve this error. trying to read data from csv fil
I have created a csv file using python code. it look like follows.

i used following statement to write in the csv file.
file_name = 'OpenPositions.xlsx'
OpenPositions.to_excel(file_name)

I am trying to read the same file through code but it is giving me following error.
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 14: invalid start byte

i tried using following. but the error doesnt go.
fno_url=r"C:\Users\Alpha Derivatives\mona\globalVariables.xlsx"
globalVariable=pd.read_csv(fno_url, encoding='utf8')


Why are you using pd.read_csv instead of pd.read_excel to read an Excel file?

ohh my god. such a silly mistake. thank you so much. Actually i am new to python. still learning. thank you so much for the help.

Yes, I got that error when using pd.read_csv. but using pd.read_excel works fine.

yes it works perfectly. thank you once again. i tried lots of things. then came here to ask the question. and turns out this a silliest mistake. thank you for the help
